# Get part of the string which is between two specific characters in php

Tags: php

I have the following string

**=220: ADDITIONAL2: HADD[][hID]=2**

I am trying to get the 220 out of this string. String that I am trying to get will always be between the '=' and the ':' characters.

My current code:

```
    $cID = explode('=', $additionalField3);
    $clientID = $cID[0];    
    echo $clientID ."<br />";
```

returns **: ADDITIONAL1: HADD[][clientID]** which is not what I want.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Is your desired number always after the `=` at the start of the string?  If your string structure doesn't vary, there may be better methods for this task.  Is the number always 3-digits or does it have variable length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to use is [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
$myString = "=220: ADDITIONAL2: HADD[][hID]=2";
preg_match('/=(.*?):/', $myString, $match);

$clientID = $match[1]; //220
```